# How do I send self as a delegate from one viewController in a tabViewController to another viewController

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uitabbarcontroller

I have a custom `tabViewController` and I would like to pass `self` as a `delegate` from `viewController` one to `viewController` two (which is modal). The problem is that when I go between `viewControllers` using the `tabs` the `prepare` function isn't triggered as the `tabViewController` handle the transitions I suppose.

So how do I make this happen? How do I pass `self` from one `viewController` to the next.

Answer (score 0):

Actually inside any VC that's inside the tab you could do

```
// suppose you need to access second tab 
if let targetVC = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers[1] as? SecondVC {
  // do what you want
}
```

Comment: Hmm, but that doesn't seem to be the same instance. If I set targetVC.testString to "aValue", then it's not showing that value when I try printing it inside the other viewController...

Comment: Can you share code ? and current scenario